# Draw a Rectangle and then draw a scale down Rectangle inside previous Rectangle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

How to draw sale down rectangle inside another rectangle? Let say I have coordinates of a rectangle which is transformed at position x,y. Now, I need to draw a scale down rectangle inside the previous recangle, Just like this,

http://www.uploadimage.co.uk/thumbs/849968trim%20Rect.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is simple, if you have the outer rectangle coordinates you must take the following steps:

1. find the center of the outer rectangle
2. move outer rectangle so that its center will coincide with origin (0,0)
3. scale the edge coordinates of outer rectangle by a ratio (ex: 0.7)
4. compute inner rectangle coordinates
5. move both outer and inner rectangle back in position

If you know a little bit of math you can actually combine all those transformation into a single one so it will be faster.

Comment: Thanks I got the answer at here, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125393/how-to-get-the-co-ordinates-of-scaled-down-polygon/125402#125402